# scheme error: application: not a procedure;

Tags: function, scheme, fractions

I'm practicing recursion in Scheme. My code below is used to return a value of continued fraction:

```
(define (fun n v)
  (define (fun-wl b v) (
                        (if (null? b)v                          ;return a value
                            (fun-wl (cdr b) (/ 1 (+ (car b) v)))))) ;first arg.list, second(1/(car b+v))
  (define (iter a b)
    (if (null? a)(fun-wl b v)             
        (iter (cdr a) (cons (car a) b)))) ;reverse list
  (iter n null)
  )
```

This is my input for scheme:

```
(fun '(1 2 3 4) 6)
```

I got this error from my code:

`application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 72/103
  arguments...: [none]`

Comment: You have a stray open parenthesis at the end of the second line. Parentheses indicate function calls in Scheme.

Comment: Did you try a google search for [`site:stackoverflow.com "application: not a procedure"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+"application%3A+not+a+procedure")?  This is a duplicate many times over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have parentheses problems, in the following line. Remember, in Lisp a pair of parentheses surrounding an expression mean "apply a function", and in this case we are *not* applying the result of the `if` expression, what we're doing is returning the value of the `if` expression itself:

```
(define (fun-wl b v) ( ; that one at the end is wrong!
```

Also the indentation can be improved, correctly formatting the code will help a lot to find this kind of problems. Try this:

```
(define (fun n v)
  (define (fun-wl b v)
    (if (null? b)
        v
        (fun-wl (cdr b) (/ 1 (+ (car b) v)))))
  (define (iter a b)
    (if (null? a)
        (fun-wl b v)             
        (iter (cdr a) (cons (car a) b))))
  (iter n null))
```

It works as expected:

```
(fun '(1 2 3 4) 6)
=> 72/103
```

Comment: Downvoter: care to comment? what's wrong with this answer, or how can I improve it?

Comment: The downvote tooltip says "this answer is not useful".  While this answer is probably useful to the asker, it's **not** as useful to the Stack Overflow site as voting to close it as a duplicate would be, perhaps with a note to the effect of "extra parentheses around `(if …)`, read the linked duplicate for more details".  Another duplicate question and answer just dilutes any attempt at a canonical answer to "application: not a procedure" questions (and there are a bunch already).